# How do I select ALL objects on canvas one by one with fabric js?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

How would the code look like to select all objects currently on a canvas one by one using fabric js. I am trying to list the attributes of each object one by one without knowing how many objects (if any) will be on the canvas.

For clarification:

Here is a https://jsfiddle.net/3bxLmwzk/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

canvas.add(new fabric.Text('hdgh', { 
    left: 20,
    top: 30, 
    fontFamily: 'Comic Sans MS',
    fontSize: 35
}));

canvas.add(new fabric.Text('foo', { 
  fontFamily: 'Roboto', 
  left: 100, 
  top: 100,
  fontSize: 25
}));

canvas.add(new fabric.Text('f776h', { 
  fontFamily: 'Arial', 
  left: 200, 
  top: 200,
  fontSize: 25
}));
```

that has 3 objects... Is there a way I can print on the console log (text, fontFamily, and fontSize) of each text object)

1 object - 'hdgh' ; Comic Sans MS ; 35
2 object - 'foo' ; Roboto ; 25
3 object - 'f776h' ; Arial ; 25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have a fabric objects, you can call `fabric.getObjects()` to get all of the objects. You can pass it a string, and that string can contain a type (like 'textbox' or 'circle') and it will only return the objects of that type.

Once you have the objects, you can loop over them as follows:

```
let objects = fabric.getObjects(); //return Array<objects>
objects.forEach(object=>{
    //list the attributes for each object
    console.log(object.text, object.fontFamily, object.fontSize);
});
```

Without a better description of what you are trying to do, this is what you can do.

Comment: By attributes, I mean the text, font family, and font size of each text object.

Comment: E.G. there are 3 objects on this canvas. How can I console.log the attributes of each object?

https://jsfiddle.net/3bxLmwzk/

Comment: You said that you want "to list the attributes". What do you mean by that?

Comment: Thank you Frosty!! This is exactly what I trying to figure out for the past couple hours and you did it in seconds. Thank you!!

Comment: Do you know how I can distinguish between objects. Text vs Image.

For text I would like the text, font family, and font size attributes, but for image I would like the image boundingRect() size H x W.

Comment: When you call `canvas.getObjects('image')` it will only return images. When you call `canvas.getObjects('Text')` it will only return text objects.

Comment: Frosty, can you help me here please??http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43152318/how-do-i-use-if-istype-for-each-object-on-a-canvas-with-fabric-js