# How do I use if isType() for each object on a canvas with fabric js?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to show certain attributes for each object on a canvas, but I am having a difficult time writing the code to do so. E.G. I want the code below to identify the difference between a shape, text, and image objects and show attributes based off the type.

Attributes to console.log:

for each object on canavas check to see if -

- Image then URL (source) and scale <= I am having a difficult time
  showing the source and name of the image.
- Text then font family, font size, color, scale
- Shape then scale and color

What do I need to add/remove/change to make it work?

Here is a JS fiddle example:
https://jsbin.com/vevihikefo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

```
canvas.getObjects().forEach(object=>{
    if(object.isType('xyz')) { // object is a shape
      console.log(object.scaleX, object.fill);
    } else if(object.isType('text')) { // object is a text
      console.log(object.text, object.fontFamily, object.fontSize*3, object.scaleX, object.fill);
    } else { // object is an image
      console.log(object.name, object.scaleX, object.fill);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that need to be added / changed, to make it work ...

- change `object.isType('xyz')` to `!object.isType('text') && !object.isType('image')`      *( as there isn't any type called 'xyz' )*
- wrap the entire code for getting the objects attributes in a *function* and call that *function* on image load, to get the image object attributes properly.

```js
fabric.Object.prototype.objectCaching = false;
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.add(new fabric.Text('foo', {
    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    fontSize: 25
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.Text('help', {
    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
    left: 100,
    top: 200,
    fontSize: 25
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.Triangle({
    fill: 'green',
    left: 200,
    top: 200
}));
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug_small.jpg', function(myImg) {
    //i create an extra var for to change some image properties
    var img1 = myImg.set({
        left: 200,
        top: 0,
        width: 150,
        height: 150
    });
    canvas.add(img1);
    getAttributes();
});
canvas.renderAll();

function getAttributes() {
    canvas.getObjects().forEach(object => {
        if (!object.isType('text') && !object.isType('image')) { // object is a shape
            console.log(object.scaleX, object.fill);
        } else if (object.isType('text')) { // object is a text
            console.log(object.text, object.fontFamily, object.fontSize * 3, object.scaleX, object.fill);
        } else if (object.isType('image')) { // object is an image
            console.log(object.name, object.scaleX, object.fill);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600" style="border: 1px solid #d3d3d3; position: absolute;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
```